# Keycloak 22.0.3: Cannot set password credential to a freshly created user using UI

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

I'm facing an issue with the Keycloak I've deployed. When I try to set a password to a user I've created using the UI (no ldap, pure keycloak user), it fails with this message: [image]

In the container logs, there is no error. The same is true for the database. I've no clue to understand what's wrong. Here is my Docker Compose configuration (I've replaced the URLs with a MY-URL):

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: MY_URL
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      #KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 443
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false
      KC_PROXY: edge
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
    volumes:
      - /home/lyxas/certs:/etc/certs
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_public"
      # HTTP
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-http.entryPoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-http.rule=Host(`MY_URL`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.keycloak-redirect-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-http.middlewares=keycloak-redirect-https"
      # HTTPS
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-https.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-https.rule=Host(`MY_URL`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-https.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-https.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-https.service=keycloak-https"
      - traefik.http.routers.keycloak-https.middlewares=waf@docker
    command: "start --hostname=MY_URL --db=postgres --features=token-exchange --db-url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${DATABASE_DATABASE} --db-username=${DATABASE_USER} --db-password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} --https-key-store-file=/etc/certs/MY_URL-keystore.jks --https-key-store-password=${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD} --http-enabled=true --log-level=debug"
    networks:
      - keycloak
      - traefik-network
  
  db:
    image: postgres:16.0-alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DATABASE_PASSWORD}'
      POSTGRES_USER: '${DATABASE_USER}'
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_DATABASE}
      TZ: 'Europe/Paris'
      PGTZ: 'Europe/Paris'
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all" ]
    networks:
      - keycloak    
    volumes:
      - '/home/lyxas/docker_data/keycloak/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data'

networks:
  keycloak:
  traefik-network:
    external:
      name: traefik_public
```

The Keycloak container and the DB seem to communicate well. My docker version is: 24.0.5, build ced0996

After the error, if I refresh the UI, I get this : [image]
But when I try to connect with the created user, it doesn't work...

EDIT: Even if there is an error when setting the credential, it seems to work, so I can log in with the new user.

I tried to set the log level to debug, but it didn't help.
I also tried to downgrade Keycloak to version [21.1.2](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/tag/21.1.2) but I'm facing the same issue

Thank you in advance for your help
Lyxas

Comment: After some tests, I still have the error when I set the credential but it seems to work. So If you have the same error, try to connect with the user, it may work.

Comment: Is there any hint in the return value of the request if you log in the browser Console (H12) Network Tab? Are you using any event-Listener?

Comment: Hey csbrogi, thank you for your comment. The only thing I see when setting the user credential is a 403 for the PUT request userLabel. The URL is in the format : https://keycloak.example.com/admin/realms/MyRealm/users/5e68e6e5-d765-484b-adaa-23698f72d7a8/credentials/485c2779-88c9-4245-993b-0738085c1d6f/userLabel . More globally, I think something is broken with my configuration. I have the same kind of issue when setting up an Email server (but this time it doesn't work at all). Removing all data did help.

Comment: With which user are you logged in? Is this an admin of the master realm? Maybe you have not the sufficient permissions to set the label. Is there  any COntent in the 403 Response?

Comment: I'm using the admin account from the master realm. Is there anything to do to gain all permissions? The content of the 403 is just an HTML page with the title "Forbidden" and the message "You don't have permission to access this resource". That's all.

Comment: That's strange. The admin user of the master realm should have all permissions in all realms, if you haven't done anything to restrict it. You can check it on the role-mappings tab for the admin user in the master realm.

Comment: It seems to have the admin role. In User > Admin > Role Mapping, I see the admin role.

Comment: Maybe this is stupid, but could it be related to proxy ? (traefik in our case). I tried to check the log of the proxy but I didn't find anything when recreating the error (even with debug log)

Comment: I tried to give the admin user all roles but it doesn't change anything